# Reverse Engineer Using Class-dump

Tags: ios

I have tried to look into the class-dump of a decompiled ipa file, can I assume that only : `TtCC29XYZ18JailbreakDetection12RuntimeClass` is of remarkable because it has `- (long long)runtimeModifiedFunction;`

```
@interface _TtC29XYZ18JailbreakDetection : _TtCs12_SwiftObject
{
}

@end

@interface _TtCC29XYZ18JailbreakDetection12RuntimeClass : _TtCs12_SwiftObject
{
}

- (long long)runtimeModifiedFunction;

--
@interface _TtC16IOSSecuritySuite16JailbreakChecker : _TtCs12_SwiftObject
{
}

@end

VAPT $ class-dump XYZ_bin | grep -A 5 -i Jail
```

Can I assume that, those without method is nothing remarkable?